# Linux socket select populates read/write fd sets but socket refuses connection

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to have a client socket make a connection to a server with a timeout.
In order to achieve the timeout, I am using a `select` call with the the `ts` set to `30s`:

```
    int flags = 0, error = 0, ret = 0;
    fd_set rset, wset;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(error);
    struct timeval ts;

    ts.tv_sec  = 0;
    ts.tv_usec = mConnectTimeoutMs * 1000; // this is 30s

    // clear out descriptor sets for select
    // add socket to the descriptor sets
    FD_ZERO(&rset);
    FD_SET(sock, &rset);
    wset = rset;

    // set socket nonblocking flag
    if ((flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0)) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    // initiate non-blocking connect
    if ((ret = ::connect(sock, sa, size)) < 0)
        if (errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            return -1;
        }

    if (ret == 0) // then connect succeeded right away
    {
        // put socket back in blocking mode
        if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // we are waiting for connect to complete now
    if ((ret = select(sock + 1, &rset, &wset, NULL, &ts)) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (ret == 0) { // we had a timeout
        errno = ETIMEDOUT;
        return -1;
    }

    // we had a positive return so a descriptor is ready
    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &rset) || FD_ISSET(sock, &wset)) {
        if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

    if (error) { // check if we had a socket error
        errno = error; // this always returns 111
        return -1;
    }
```

The point of the timeout is to allow time for the server to spawn & the server socket to be listening/accepting.
For some reason, without the server running, the `select` call falls through immediatly, with the `rset` and `wset` both returning true from `FD_ISSET(sock`.

Calling:
`getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len)`
Always results in the error being populated with error code `111` (connection refused), which is expected, since the server is not running yet. What am i doing wrong here If I want the select to wait for the socket to be ready to actually connect? Or how can I correctly "wait for the server socket to exist to connect" using a timeout?

Comment: You have a timeout of 0 which is not long, and tv_usec is uninitialized, that surely sounds like an issue ? Make sure you check the return value of all calls you make for errors also. If all that is ok, perhaps you have not correctly initialized the sockaddr in your `sa` variable - leading your code do trying to connect to something other that what you think it should.

Comment: If the server isn't running you'll get an immediate `ECONNREFUSED` error when you call `connect()`. It doesn't keep retrying, and `select()` won't block. You need retry logic in your code.

Comment: @nos sorry that was a typo in the reference example it was 30

Comment: @Barmar i receive `EINPROGRESS` as the error on the connect without the server running (the socket is set to nonblocking)

Comment: You receive EINPROGRESS until the RST is received from the server, then it changes to ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: @Barmar so you would expect the select to fall through in the case of no server? can you explain conceptually what fd triggers the select to fall through in that case?

Comment: You get EINPROGRESS when you first call `connect()`, because it's non-blocking. Then `select()` will block until a reply is received from the server. If the reply is a SYN, it means the connection succeeded, and the socket will be in the write set. If the reply is a RST, it means the server isn't running, and the socket will be in both the read and write sets, and any read/write call will return ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: @rob The connect finishes. It finishes, with the answer being "no you can't connect there". Since the connect finished, select tells you that it finished and the error code tells you why you can't connect there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Barmar's comments, the select falls through as a result of the RST when the server socket is not yet listening, and the resulting socket will have an error (ECONNREFUSED). To achieve the timeout as intended, we can wrap the existing logic in a do/while loop, and then modify the timeout value to by dynamic based on remaining time in the timeout:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
...
    int timeoutRemaining                        = mConnectTimeoutMs;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    do {
       // same conn logic as before, except:
        ...
        ts.tv_usec = timeoutRemaining * 1000;
        ...
        if (error) { // check if we had a socket error
            errno = error;
            if (errno == ECONNREFUSED) {
                close(sock); // can't call connect on a socket thats refused connection
                sock = create_new_sock();
                // artificially throttle connection requests
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                continue; // there is no server available, continue trying until we reach our connection timeout
            }
            return -1;
        }
   ...
    } while ((timeoutRemaining = (mConnectTimeoutMs
                                  - (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                                         std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start)
                                         .count())))
            > 0);
```